# iOS 10.3 UISegmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes Crash

Tags: ios, swift, ios10.3

iOS 10.3 crashes on `UISegmentedControl`'s `setTitleTextAttributes` method.

Question:

1. What is the reason for the crash?
2. What is the solution?

Note: Have already reported this issue to apple, but haven't yet heard from them.
https://openradar.appspot.com/31448227

Sample Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()         
        //Crash!        
        segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0) : NSFontAttributeName], for: .normal)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As @vedian pointed out, it should be `[key : value]` and not the other way around, but the **above code doesn't crash on iOS versions below 10.3**.

Comment: any code? that would be easier. Any attribute or you have tried only font?

Comment: @Lu_ well i migrated to swift 3.1 as well, but it still crashes, you can test yourself.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala it works for me. Check your IBOutlet connection.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR 10.3?

Comment: 10.2 and attributes should be in `[key:value]` format `[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)]`. Try changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing the issue, not Apple.

A dictionary is created in order first `key` then `value`.

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Alright, will try this. I din't notice that. Thanks. But why does it work with swift 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)], for: .normal)
```

instead of

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0) : NSFontAttributeName], for: .normal)
```